# MSMQ no error but message stuck in outgoing

Tags: c#, msmq, msmq-transaction

I am trying to send MSMQ message using TCP but the message is just stuck in Outgoing queue . Also when I am creating MessageQueue object it does not throws any error but on putting a breakpoint and trying to see the Properties I can see errors like for Authenticate i get error "The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.".

The for connection I am using below code.

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue("FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:<IP Address>\\PRIVATE$\\TestQueue");
```

Even the OS format is not working. Please help.

Comment: "Authenticate"? We need a bit more information here. What properties are set on the queue (authenticated, privacy, etc.)? Transactional or not? What is the status of the outgoing queue?

Comment: the State in outgoing queue is "Waiting to connect " and the Connecttion History says ""Failed to connect Winsock socket. Address:IP=xx.xx.xx.xx"

Comment: Also this is a Transactional queue. To resolve the connection issue I have  Enabled Remote Event Monitor (RPC-EPMAP) inbound rule in firewall have given full rights to Everyone on  the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to receive messages from a remote queue. This is very different to sending messages to a remote queue. One uses RPC and the other MSMQ.

As you discovered, opening up RPC ports in the firewall is essential.

[Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)

Comment: No,I am trying to send message to remote queue and its stuck in outgoing. As per the article I have check to messaging services in Fire wall and the rule to allow is enabled.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you meant you resolved the issue by changing the firewall rules.